# Connecting two Health Devices via bluetooth with Android to get Readings from Health Device

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, serversocket

I'm developing an android app that reads values from health device and pass that readings to my server.The app supports for two medical devices Ultra Touch mini Gluco meter and A&D Medical pressure meter. For getting readings from both devices i'm using two Services one for Gluco Meter and another for Pressure Meter.I have launched my app in Android device and exit from the app but the two services run in background and looking for remote devices, When i take reading from one device such as Pressure meter it will ask for Pairing request but this call come from Polymap service. Each service is looking for connection with remote device using same UUID.How to stop Pairing code request come from Polymap service when i take reading in Pressure meter.

In Short Service A - Pressure Meter and Service B - Gluco meter when i take reading in Pressure Meter it asks for pairing code from Service B. How to solve this?

Please give your suggestions to achieve this.

1. Is it advisable to listen for remote devices using 2 separate  BluetoothServerSockets?
2. How to stop Polymap.jar to support only for Gluco Meter ?
3. Is there anyway to find which device is requesting for pairing code?

Thanks.